# center '+' inside the border-radius 50% div?

Tags: css

I'd like to center a + inside a div. The problem is on ios it shows more in the bottom of the div and not in the middle. in chrome it is ok.
Any ideas to solve this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfas65t9/)

```css
.addplus {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 38px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class='addplus'>
  +
</div>
```

Comment: what font-family are you using?

Comment: font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;  @zgood

Comment: Helvetica doesn't have really good windows support (ref: https://www.cssfontstack.com/Helvetica), so maybe on ios Helvetica is rendering and on chrome it is falling back to Arial (the `+` glyph can have different positioning for different fonts). I dunno... maybe try making the plus sign with borders and puesdo elements or use an image

Comment: I add font-family: arial and it works on both! thanks friend! @zgood

Comment: lol ya that works to I guess

Comment: @zgood Fonts and especially symbols inside of the fonts have varying sizes/widths. You might want to convert the + you're using to an image/svg with it in the exact center of a square artboard. Then you can more easily position it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Ios device near me right now so I can't be sure if it works, but try this:

Put the "+" in a span, then center the span in the div instead.

Something like this:

```css
    .addplus {
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: blue;
      width: 38px;
      height: 38px;
      margin: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 38px;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 38px;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    }

    .plus {
      position: absolute;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 38px;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="addplus">
  <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>
```